# lotus notes you cannot forward or otherwise copy the contents of this document

Tags: lotus-notes

There is a Lotus Notes application containing >8k documents, listed by some views.

A user showed this error, while he tried to copy ( from one document being in read-mode, we tried also in edit-mode ) some content ( value fields ) to another document ( into some fields ). Strangely, the error is showing only for a certain document ( of course we didn't try for all of 8k docs, but we try for other 5-6 docs and the error didn't showed up. )

```
You cannot forward or otherwise copy the contents of this document.
This document is set to prohibit copying and duplicating.
```

I read that it might be an admin problem. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document has probably a field `$KeepPrivate` set to "1". If you delete the field you can copy the content into clipboard again.

As a developer you can let create such a field for documents if you set option "**Disable printing/forwarding/copying to clipboard**" in security tab in form properties.

[image]

Comment: Could you solve the issue deleting item $KeepPrivate?

Comment: Indeed, the docs I can't copy - they do have $KeepPrivate=1. The other docs, which I can copy them, they don't have such item. I have looked into the Document Properties.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. That's what I meant with "... delete the field".

Answer (score 0):

The $KeepPrivate item that Knut described may exist because of an ACL setting instead of the Form setting.  There is a setting on each ACL entry labeled 'Replicate or copy documents'.  Users who do not have this setting enabled will not be able to copy documents, but there is a side effect which is described in [this IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21164209). I.e., when a user who has this ACL setting creates documents, those documents are marked with the $KeepPrivate item. This prevents everyone from copying the document, even people who don't have that box checked in their own ACL entries.  IBM does not consider this a bug. I consider it a design flaw.

Comment: The users have the rights to replicate or copy documents.